# check if image exist taking much time if image is not valid

Tags: php, curl

I have a function to check if image is valid, and if it is print the img on the screen.

```
<?php
function isImage($url){

$url_headers=get_headers($url, 1);

if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   $url_exists = false;
} 
else {
    $url_exists = true;
}

if($url_exists){
    if(isset($url_headers['Content-Type'])){
        $type=strtolower($url_headers['Content-Type']);

        $valid_image_type=array();
        $valid_image_type['image/png']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpg']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpeg']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpe']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/gif']='';

        if(isset($valid_image_type[$type])){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}

if(isImage("http://curiosidadeslegais.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/zuera-pa-w5app.jpg")){
echo '<img src="http://curiosidadeslegais.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/zuera-pa-w5app.jpg" alt="">';
}
```

the problem is I don't know why the page is taking so long in the url above. The image no longer exists. and the html prints:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="nosnippet" />
</head>
<body>
<div align=center>
<h3>Error. Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details.  (9)</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it is taking to long to my function to verify it is not an image and ignores it. any ideas why?

It should be fast to check if image exists or not to print it or not. but in this case it is taking so long.

Comment: Try it with a different image... The image link you gave does not directly link to an image resource.

Comment: @JordanS with different image it works. the problem, that I'm asking is why in this particular case it is taking so much time to the response be false. There is no image in this url, but php taking about 30 seconds to answer false.

Comment: It seems you are relying on a 404 in the header. Which if some site is dishing custom output for a url (like that one)... it may not actually include the proper headers, due to reasons. And a possible reason why its 'slow' is that url you are hitting, is doing either a wait to slow down bots, or its just a crappy server.

Comment: @IncredibleHat any ideas to avoid this delay? it is breaking my website.

Comment: Other than talking directly to the server owner and having them setup an url that doesn't do any delays... you are SOL I would think. OR, you do a timed parsing, and store a local result set for the live activity.

Comment: @IncredibleHat add a time out or things like this...

Comment: Have you tried condition: `if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
   $url_exists = true;` And then... `else $url_exists = false;`

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents can return headers and have a max timeout set.

```
$options = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
array(
    "timeout" => 1, // one second
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
));

$url_headers = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
```

This is untested since I'm typing on my phone.

Another thing I notice in your code is the `$url_exists = true;` why? Why not just move the code below up and replace above line with everything inside the `if($url_exists == true)`.
It's not the reason for the slow code but it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I add this to limit the time to search for image. I don't know if it is the best way, but...

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);
```

Comment: Did you even try my suggestion?

Comment: @Andreas I tried! but I don't know why, the timeout didn't work. I don't know if I put the $options in the right place... or something. the ini_set works.